# Can Google Checkout support the Parallel Payments like Paypal

Tags: google-checkout

I have created a Event website and here registered user can create event and their tickets and when an event is created then other users purchases tickets. when customer pays for the tickets then the payment goes to the two person ie. 1(Ticket Owner),2(Website Owner). there are two payment gateways one is Paypal and second is Google Checkout.
I have implement Paypal Parallel Payments for this and want to know that there are any options in Google Checkout like Paypal for this type payment. please let me know as soon aspossible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no equivalent to PayPal Parallel Payments in Google Checkout.